# Postgres substring error

Tags: postgresql, view, substring, strpos

I am receiving an error when creating a view converted from code at website http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2007/02/passing-variable-to-in-list.html.  `ERROR: function pg_catalog.substring(text,bigint,integer) does not exist;` #7.  Appreciate your help.

Code:

```
WITH recursive Hierarchy(ChildId, SubRepInitials, ParentId, Parents, steps)
AS
(
    SELECT salesforceid, salesforceinitials, parentid, CAST('' AS TEXT), 0 as steps
        FROM tblbulksalesforce AS FirstGeneration
        WHERE parentid IS NULL AND salesforceinitials IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NextGeneration.salesforceid, NextGeneration.salesforceinitials, Parent.ChildId,
    CAST(CASE WHEN Parent.Parents = ''
        THEN(CAST(NextGeneration.parentid AS TEXT) || ',')
        ELSE(Parent.Parents || CAST(NextGeneration.parentid AS TEXT) || ',')
    END AS TEXT), Parent.steps +1 as steps
        FROM tblbulksalesforce AS NextGeneration
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.parentid = Parent.ChildId 
        WHERE NextGeneration.salesforceinitials IS NOT NULL   
)
    SELECT ISNULL(h.ParentId,h.ChildId) AS ParentId, h.ChildId
        , h.SubRepInitials, h.Parents, steps
        ,Generation0.salesforceinitials AS RepInitials
        ,parent.salesforceinitials AS RepInitialsParent
    FROM Hierarchy AS h
    LEFT JOIN tblbulksalesforce AS parent ON parent.RecordID = h.ParentId
    LEFT JOIN tblbulksalesforce AS Generation0 ON Generation0.RecordID IN (
             (SELECT SUBSTRING(string, 2, strpos(',', string, 2) - 2)
                FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(list, n, character_length(list))
                        FROM (SELECT ',' || h.Parents || ',') AS L(list),
                        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY parentid)
                            FROM Hierarchy) AS Nums(n)
                            WHERE n <=  character_length(list)) AS D(string) 
                        WHERE character_length(string) > 1 AND SUBSTRING(string, 1, 1) = ',')
    ) OR Generation0.RecordID = h.ChildId;
```

Comment: You need to explicitly cast your bigint 'n' to integer or a type coerceable to integer.

Comment: Here is how to use [substring](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) function

Comment: Revised      (SELECT SUBSTRING(string, 2, strpos(CAST(',' AS TEXT), string, 2) - 2)
    FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(list,CAST(n AS INT), character_length(list)) and now receive error function strpos(text,text,integer) does not exist.

Comment: Please note this website was also used in creating view: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child

Answer (score 0):

Please see Postgres [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) for how to use `strpos()` and `substr()`.  Note that `substring()` is a completely different function with a different format for its arguments.

Try this:

```
WITH recursive Hierarchy(ChildId, SubRepInitials, ParentId, Parents, steps)
AS
(
    SELECT salesforceid, salesforceinitials, parentid, CAST('' AS TEXT),     0 as steps
      FROM tblbulksalesforce AS FirstGeneration
      WHERE parentid IS NULL AND salesforceinitials IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NextGeneration.salesforceid, NextGeneration.salesforceinitials, Parent.ChildId,
    CAST(CASE WHEN Parent.Parents = ''
      THEN(CAST(NextGeneration.parentid AS TEXT) || ',')
      ELSE(Parent.Parents || CAST(NextGeneration.parentid AS TEXT) || ',')
    END AS TEXT), Parent.steps +1 as steps
      FROM tblbulksalesforce AS NextGeneration
      INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.parentid = Parent.ChildId 
      WHERE NextGeneration.salesforceinitials IS NOT NULL   
)
SELECT ISNULL(h.ParentId,h.ChildId) AS ParentId, h.ChildId
    , h.SubRepInitials, h.Parents, steps
    ,Generation0.salesforceinitials AS RepInitials
    ,parent.salesforceinitials AS RepInitialsParent
FROM Hierarchy AS h
LEFT JOIN tblbulksalesforce AS parent ON parent.RecordID = h.ParentId
LEFT JOIN tblbulksalesforce AS Generation0 ON Generation0.RecordID IN (
         (SELECT SUBSTR(string, 2, strpos(',', string) - 2) -- you had a 2 sitting in strpos(',', string, 2) before.  I'm not sure what you were trying to do with that. 
            FROM (SELECT SUBSTR(list, n, character_length(list))
                    FROM (SELECT ',' || h.Parents || ',') AS L(list),
                    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY parentid)
                        FROM Hierarchy) AS Nums(n)
                        WHERE n <=  character_length(list)) AS D(string) 
                    WHERE character_length(string) > 1 AND SUBSTR(string, 1, 1) = ',')
) OR Generation0.RecordID = h.ChildId;
```

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP.  Upon further research Postgres does not have a charindex/instr functionality that I was trying to adapt from the referenced website.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it didn't have some tool to get the job done (e.g. regex functions), but I'm honestly not going to spend the time sorting through that website to figure out what you're doing.  If you could post a(some) sample table(s) and expected output, I'm sure we could figure something out to do what you need.